# Python Call graph for only Python files

Tags: python, flowchart

I used this open source  [Here](https://github.com/autorope/donkey2) in order to make an autonomous driving car.

The entire project consists of many folders and python files located  inside them.
Unfortunately, I don’t know how all of these python files are connected. I do though understand the main files and what they do.

I wanted to make a flowchart on how each python file is connected to each other.
Is it possible to create a flowchart of only the python files (not including the functions and oher stuff) ?

I have read a bit about module “Python call graph “ but not sure if it would serve me regarding this problem

Open for any idea on how to show the structure of the project in a graphic way. I want to use it for my documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be a "flowchart" - a flowchart  represents a workflow or process - nor a call graph (which represents which function/method called which other function/method), but a dependency graph, IOW which module (or script) depends  on which other module ("depends on" => "uses things defined in").

This can be found out by checking the imports. Unless there are [dynamic imports](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), this can be done quite simply by static analysis (manual - just read the code and report what you find on a paper sheet - or automated using grep and/or similar tools), just reading the `import` statements in each module.

Or you can of course try one of the already existing python packages doing this - now you know the term to look for ("dependency graph"), you should (hopefully) be able to find something usable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also interested in software visualization.
For Python I found but didn't test this:

https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps

https://www.scivision.dev/python-dependency-graph/

I'll be glad to read your research results.